# Moving arrays from cells to column headers and row values

Tags: python, pandas

With below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Brand': [['Honda', 'Toyota'],['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Ford'],['Ford','Toyota']],
        'Price': [[10,12],[15,18,11],[11,12]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Brand                   Price
0   [Honda, Toyota]         [10, 12]
1   [Toyota, Honda, Ford]   [15, 18, 11]
2   [Ford, Toyota]          [11, 12]
```

I would like to transform it, making **Brand** entries my column names and **Price** cell values, to look like this:

```
    Honda   Toyota  Ford
0   10      12      NaN
1   18      15      11
2   NaN     12      11
```

Unfortunately both the order of entries in the array and their appearance varies across over 200k records. Is it possible to do to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with

```
s = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(x, y)) for x , y in zip(df['Brand'], df['Price'])])
Out[403]: 
   Honda  Toyota  Ford
0   10.0      12   NaN
1   18.0      15  11.0
2    NaN      12  11.0
```

Comment: Thanks BEN_YO. It works well for the data set i provided! I tried to apply it to my real life data set when there are up to 8 Brands and Prices with over 100k rows but the outcome is weird, as each character is split into separate cell. I tried to alter the code to accommodate those conditions but no luck so far.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode).set_index('Brand', append=True)['Price'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
Brand Ford Honda Toyota
0      NaN    10     12
1       11    18     15
2       11   NaN     12
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. I tried to apply it to my real data with up to 8 Brands and 8 Prices and over 100k rows and got the following error: `ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow`

Comment: @saif3r Yep, looks like there is a bug or enhancement needed in pandas to fix this issue.  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26314